# Splitting monitor using xrandr

Tags: xorg, display-resolution, xrandr

I'm trying to split my 4k screen using xrandr to 3 sections,
the output of `xrandr` is

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1200     60.00 +
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 700mm x 390mm
   3840x2160     30.00*+  25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

When i ran these commands

```
xrandr --setmonitor HDMI1~1 960/175x2160/390+0+0 HDMI1
xrandr --setmonitor HDMI1~2 1920/350x2160/390+960+0 none
xrandr --setmonitor HDMI1~3 960/175x2160/390+2880+0 none
```

I get this output

```
output list HDMI1
add monitor HDMI1
output name HDMI1
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  43 ()
  Value in failed request:  0x1445
  Serial number of failed request:  42
  Current serial number in output stream:  43
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  43 ()
  Value in failed request:  0x1446
  Serial number of failed request:  42
  Current serial number in output stream:  43
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  43 ()
  Value in failed request:  0x144b
  Serial number of failed request:  42
  Current serial number in output stream:  43
```

The parameters i used seem to be within range, i need a set fresh of eyes to help me figure out what i'm missing